keen-slider stop on mouse-over
How to make it so that in the slider when hovering over the arrow buttons the slide stops and starts working only after the mouse cursor is removed?
Here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/jovial-wood-fy2frt?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A1%2C1-124%2C1
